# Fatal error: Call to a member function getPk() on a non-object (P4A, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Not too sure on what this error is, from looking around, it must be something to do with the database declarations. I'm trying to make a drop down box on my Widget, by selecting different fields of the database, different masks will be selected and will allow for different widgets to be made on later pages.

The part of my code where i think the error is, is:

```
$this->build("p4a_db_source", "login")
        ->setTable("meetingrooms")
        ->addJoin("login.meetingrooms",
                  "login.meetingrooms.MeetingRoom = login.meetingrooms.MeetingRoom",
                  array('position'=>'Ident'))
        ->addOrder("position")
        ->load();

    $this->setSource($this->login);
    $this->firstRow();
    $this->build('p4a_field','location')
    ->setSource('login')
    ->setLabel('location')
    ->setValue('Please Select...')
    ->setType('select')     
    ->setWidth(60);
    $this->weight->label->setWidth(60);
```

I know its a similar question to my previous one, but its a different code entirely, but this one should be much easier to fix.
Thanks for the help.

The Stacktrace (Fatal error: Call to a member function getPk() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\p4a\p4a\objects\widgets\field.php on line 468) isn't indicating the line at which the error is occurring so i'm unsure where exactly the problem is originating from,

The rest of the code (including previous) is:

```
class main_dashboard_mask extends P4A_Base_Mask
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTitle("Dashboard");

    $this->build('p4a_field','MeetingRooms');
    $this->MeetingRooms->setLabel("This is the meeting room label");
    $this->build('p4a_button', 'continue')
    ->setLabel('Continue?')
    ->implement("onclick", $this, "change");
   $this->build('p4a_field','booking')
    ->setlabel('Viewing?')
    ->setType('checkbox')
    ->setValue(true);
    $this->booking->label->setTooltip('If you are booking a meeting room, check this box');

    $this->build("p4a_db_source", "login")
        ->setTable("meetingrooms")
        ->addJoin("login.meetingrooms",
                  "login.meetingrooms.MeetingRoom = login.meetingrooms.MeetingRoom",
                  array('position'=>'Ident'))
        ->addOrder("position")
        ->load();

    $this->setSource($this->login);
    $this->firstRow();
    $this->build('p4a_field','location')
    ->setSource('login')
    ->setLabel('location')
    ->setValue('Please Select...')
    ->setType('select')     
    ->setWidth(60);
    $this->weight->label->setWidth(60);
    $this->Meetingrooms();
}

private function Meetingrooms()
{
    $this->build('P4A_fieldset', 'widgetframe')
    ->anchor($this->location)
    ->anchorLeft($this->booking)
    ->anchorLeft($this->continue)
    ->setLabel('Meeting Room Bookings');
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it, sorry i was looking in the right place but didn't see where i was wrong...

where before the code was ->

```
 $this->setSource($this->login);
$this->firstRow();
$this->build('p4a_field','location')
->setSource('login') // <- this is the error(the Pk variable hasn't been set here)
->setLabel('location')
->setValue('Please Select...')
->setType('select')     
->setWidth(60);
$this->weight->label->setWidth(60);
$this->Meetingrooms();
```

the fix is ->

```
 ->setSource($this->login)
```

Thanks for the assistance =]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not getting the object. That is why it's giving error of non-object.
Just print the object on which you are calling the method getPk(). If it is valid object then
only call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a full stacktrace ? What line of code exactly generates this error ?

Anyway, you have to locate the code where `$object->getPk()` is called. The error means that you're trying to use a function `->getPk()` on an `$object` that is `null` ..

Comment: @ Ajay Khedkar there is no indication of where exactly the error is originating from, and as can be above in my previous code, there is no mention of the function 'getpk()' or even 'setpk()' I'm completely baffled by this :S

Comment: there is no part of my code which uses ->getPk() so how can it be generating this error? (im getting annoyed with p4a XD) even on the preious masks, i dont have a ->getPk() function declared anywhere unless one of the functions is linked to it somehow, any clue which one it could be?

Comment: We understood that getPk() is not in your code .. but it is called anymway.. you need to find where .. Do you have a debug tool ? if no .. comment one by one each of your lines to understand the one that called getPk() ini background..